# ValueError: X has 4 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 1 features as input

Tags: python, lstm

```
index = [496,495,498,499]

candles = scaler.transform(np.array([float(check[i][4]) for i in index]).reshape(1,-1))

model_feed = candles.reshape(1,4,1)

scaler.inverse_transform(model.predict(model_feed)[0])[0] #at 7:08 PM prediction today 6th April
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-669db369d0af> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 index = [496,495,498,499]
      2 
----> 3 candles = scaler.transform(np.array([float(check[i][4]) for i in index]).reshape(1,-1))
      4 
      5 model_feed = candles.reshape(1,4,1)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    387 
    388         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
--> 389             raise ValueError(
    390                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    391                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."

ValueError: X has 4 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 1 features as input.
```